# iOS app icon using ionic command

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I have auto generated app icon using "ionic cordova resources ios" command.The icon generated for iOS having black border around the app icon and not looking properly .Do we need to manually create the icons with recommended iOS app icon sizes? . Has anyone faced similar kind of issues?. please suggest.

Note :The icon is having For android icon looks good at all different resolutions

Comment: Do you generate your app icons from an `.psd`? The iOS shows the icon with rounded corners, while the icon for Android has sharp corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ionic using automated Icon generation for iOS and Android app and due to that your Icon have black border around.

**Black border reason :**

Your Main Icon have some transparency or transparent area around your Icon.  or may be your Icon is already have corner radius.

**Solution :** Please remove transparency from your icon and corner radius and  again generate your iOS icon will remove black border.

> Note: iPhone OS automatically add corner radius so not required to add
>   it in our app icon.

Hope this Info will help to solve your problem!

Comment: Ho do you remove transparency from the icon and corner radius?